# capybara find regex results in DOM Exception 12

Tags: rspec, capybara

the following works:

```
find("#delete-category-link")
```

i want also to find 'delete-category-link-8' or 'delete-category-link-9'.

when i try with regex ^:

```
find('#^delete-category-link')
```

or

```
find('id^="delete-category-link"')
```

i get

```
Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:    
SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute selectors need to be enclosed by the `[` and `]`. It should be:

```
find('[id^="delete-category-link"]')
```